# Can I change zlib compression level in the same file

Tags: zlib

Will I corrupt the output if I

1. Write data to a file with compression level (say) 6.
2. Close that zstream and open a new zstream, calling `deflateInit` with a different compression level (say, 1), and append that data to the same file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will corrupt the output, in the sense that zlib decoders are not expecting concatenated zlib streams.

It doesn't matter though, since you don't need to end the zlib stream to change the compression level.  The `deflateParams()` function allows you to change the compression level and compression strategy mid-stream.  Please read the documentation in `zlib.h`.